# R If Statement order of evaluation

Tags: r, if-statement, operator-precedence

I have to migrate an R script to Python and found the following if chain in R:

```
PreparedData <- PreparedData %>% mutate(T.Churn3 = ifelse(lead(T.Purchases) == 0 & T.Purchases > 0 | lead(T.Purchases, 2) == 0 & lead(T.Purchases) > 0 & T.Purchases >0 | lead(T.Purchases, 2) == 0 & lead(T.Purchases) == 0 & T.Purchases >0, 1, 0))
```

Now I'm struggling with the evaluation order here for R. For me this statement looks unnecessarily bloated. This is how I understand the order of evaluation:

1. Check if Purchases of the next row is zero and if purchases of the current row is bigger than zero.
2. If 1. does not apply check if the purchases 2 rows ahead is zero and the purchase of the next row and the purchase of the acual row are bigger than zero
3. If 1. and 2. do not apply check if the purchases 2 rows ahead is zero, the purchases of the next row is zero and the current purchases is bigger than zero

I'm really not sure if that is right, but it is the only thing which could barely make sense to me. If that assumption of mine is right, then the third statement part would be unnecessary because the first statement part is part of the third statement.

Can anyone shed some light here?

Best regards,
André

Comment: This is not how `|` and `&` work in R. All logical statements are evaluated (and thus evaluation order doesn't matter). The non-vectorized operators `&&` and `||` don't evaluate the RHS if it isn't necessary but they can't be used here (because `ifelse` is vectorized).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Roland's comment I think I was able to figure out what that statement actually does and it indeed is not very efficient. So for anyone else struggling with the logical operators maybe the following approach can also help:

Starting from left I looked at each logical operation and wrote their outcome as T/F one line below. After that I used the T/F with the next part of the logical chain until I reached the end of the line. In the end the picture looked like that:

[image]

The rest I had to do was to put in all possibilities and after that I noticed that the whole chain can be simplified to:

```
ifelse(lead(T.Purchases) == 0 & lead(T.Purchases,2) == 0 & T.Purchases > 0,1,0)
```